# How to convert a PermutationGroup to a named group

Tags: permutation, group-theory

We can convert any built-in named group into `PermutationGroup` by this code(such as `AlternatingGroup[5]`):

```
G = FiniteGroupData[{"AlternatingGroup", 5}, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]
```

> PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 4}}],
> Cycles[{{1, 2, 5}}]}]

But how to convert a `PermutationGroup` to a named group(If it is indeed a named group)?

Comment: Do you know of an algorithm to do that? I am not sure that I can see how this would be done in principle, let alone in MMA.

Comment: @MarcoB I don't know, but [*Maple*](https://www.maplesoft.com/) can identity group in [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups) by `IdentifySmallGroup`.

Comment: @MarcoB Done. :)

Comment: @MarcoB in [gap](https://www.gap-system.org) this can be done with [`IdSmallGroup`](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/SmallGrp/doc/chap1.html). Something like `IdSmallGroup(Group((1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5)));`

Comment: @Roman How do I call gap with MMA?

Comment: I don't know how to call GAP from Mathematica, apart from the obvious [`RunThrough`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunThrough.html). I've been hoping for GAP/Mathematica integration for many years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
named = FiniteGroupData[GroupOrder[G]];
Select[named, FiniteGroupData[#, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"] == G &]
```

> {{AlternatingGroup,5}}

---

Or not get the exactly equal but isomorphic group. Then we can use this code(The `isomorphicGroupsQ` is from [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FindGroupIsomorphism/)):

```
isomorphicGroupsQ[g1_, g2_] := Equal[
    Length @ ResourceFunction["FindGroupIsomorphism"][g1, g2, 1],
    1
]
```

Then the code can be:

```
named=FiniteGroupData[GroupOrder[G]];
Select[named,isomorphicGroupsQ[G,
       FiniteGroupData[#,"PermutationGroupRepresentation"]]&]
```

> {{AlternatingGroup,5}}